# video js error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, thumbnails, video.js

I'm using `videojs` and `dailymotion.js` to play the video of dailymotion. I also used `videojs.thumbnails.js` to show the thumbnails. But such a simply code generate an strange error in `video.js`:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Video.js Thumbnails Example</title>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="videojs.thumbnails.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.3/video.js"></script>
  <script src='videojs.thumbnails.js'></script>
  <script src='dailymotion.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

<video id='video'
       class='video-js vjs-default-skin'
       width='640'
       height='264'
       controls> 
</video>
<script>
// initialize video.js
var video = videojs('video',{ "techOrder": ["dailymotion","html5"], "src": "https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x378j01"});

// here's an example of generating thumbnails from a sprited image: 
video.thumbnails({
  0: {
    src: 'example-thumbnail.png'
  }
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The error in the console is :

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>
> t.sc  @   video.js:47
>
> t.duration    @   video.js:49
>
> t.sc  @   video.js:47
>
> t.duration    @   video.js:49
>
> ...

It seems like a loop, but I don't know where it came from, any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put videojs code after page load.Try this

```
$(function(){
var video = videojs('video',{ "techOrder": ["dailymotion","html5"], "src": "https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x378j01"});

// here's an example of generating thumbnails from a sprited image: 
video.thumbnails({
  0: {
    src: 'example-thumbnail.png'
  }
});
});
```

Comment: You need to place jquey file on page after that it will work.

Comment: if still it  gives error share console log on comment.

Comment: I tried with video-js 5.0 it worked, but just didn't work for video-js 4.3, that bothers me cause I have some plugins incompatible with the version 5.0...